# Spring Data JPA transitive query method

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

Is it possible in Spring Data JPA to create transitive query method? E.g. :

Game entity:

```
public class Game{
    long id;
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<User> users;
}
```

User entity:

```
public class User{
    long id;
    String lastName;
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "users")
    private Set<Game> games;
}
```

I tried to create method: `List<User> findGameUsersByIdOrderByLastName(long gameId);` in my `GameRepository` extending `CrudRepository`.
I want to get `Users` from `Game` ordered by `LastName`. It doesn't work. Is it even possible to do something like this?

Comment: 1. You have two separate unidirectional many-to-many relationships between `Game` and `User`. Are you sure that's what you want? 2. The method should read `findUsersByIdOrderByUsersLastName` as you're already in the context of a `Game` and selecting a specific field, i.e. `users`. It would seem more logical to query for users in `UserRepository`, though (the method would read `findByGameIdOrderByLastName`)

Comment: Ad. 1 Edited my code. Ad 2. Problem is that `User` can have a lot of `Games` and I need only these connected with given `Game`. Wouldn't be querying for `Users` in `UserRepository` inefficient( lot of users, each with lot of games connected ).

Comment: No, I don't think it would. Why should it? The relationship is symmetrical, and both resulting queries involve two joins (to the other entity's table via the joining table)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use here   @Query:

```
@Query("SELECT u FROM User u join u.games g where g.id = :gameid order by u.lastName")
        Set<> customMethodName(@Param("gameid") Long gameid);
```

You can get more info about @Query from [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.at-query)